# Setting an Option set Value depending on Parent Account Type

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, setvalue, picklist

I am having trouble getting the Option set Field to Populate. I have to set an Option set Value to either a Facility or Vendor on a Child account, depending on if the Parent Account Type is a Facility or Vendor.

```
function SetOptionSetField(accountType)
{
    var options = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(new_type).setValue(100000002, 100000003);

    if (accountType === 100000000) {
        new_type.setValue(100000002);
    }
    else if (accountType === 100000001) {
        new_type.setValue(100000003)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show some of your code?

Comment: function SetOptionSetField(accountType) {

    var options = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(new_type).setValue(100000002, 100000003);
    


    if (accountType === 100000000) {

        new_type.setValue(100000002);
    }

    else if (accountType === 100000001) {

        new_type.setValue(100000003)
    }

}

Comment: Please take in mind I am new to JavaScript.

Comment: put it in with the question and format it for more readability to the viewers.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: glad you put time to place and format your code. Cause if you dont, you will get downvotes and will no longer be able to ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `new_type` is the name of an attribute. Try this:

```
function SetOptionSetField(accountType)
{
    var typeField = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_type");

    if (accountType === 100000000) {
        typeField.setValue(100000002);
    }
    else if (accountType === 100000001) {
        typeField.setValue(100000003)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I did not work unfortunately .new_type  is the name of the field that I am trying to get to populate depending on the accountType value that is selected.

Comment: Just use the code above and step through it using your browser's debugger. Several things can be wrong: your function may not be called, accountType may have hold an unexpected value etc.